# How to prevent water coming off the edge of a roof with no gutter?

Tags: roof, roofing, gutters

On the side of our house that is perpendicular to the main roof ridge the roof (the ladders?) extends further by the ridge than it does down by the eaves. As a result, rain that hits close to the end of the ridge, as it flows down the roof, eventually falls off the edge of the roof instead of going all the way to the gutter. The image below is my attempt at a diagram:

[image]

My instinct was to use an drip edge upside down, but that turns out to be quite the eyesore. My guess is that there is a professional solution to this but I can't seem to find anything in the usual forums. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

That edge of your roof is called the “rake” edge.

Water is probably running off it because 1) it’s slightly lower than the main roof, or 2) heavy rain and wind pushes it off that edge.

To keep the water from coming off the rake edge, is recommend a “standing seam” edge. The height will depend on how much rain you get and the length of the rake edge.

Here, we get a lot of rain all at once and we use a 3/4” to 1” high standing ridge at the edge, depending on the length of run.

Comment: Thank you Lee! Please excuse my ignorance - is a standing seam edge a part you buy and attach after the fact? It's a new shingle roof and I my assumption was to screw in the edge straight through the shingles?

Comment: No, the edge flashing is normally about 4” wide and lays flat on the roof and then turns down over the edge about 3”. This flashing lays flat on the roof but then turns up about 1” and then turns down (180 degrees) and is about 4”. (3” normal coverage plus the 1” it was turned up).

Comment: @nodapic You can get that custom made, its also called a rain diverter, although that often has an extra bend, but not necessary (https://www.riversidesheetmetal.net/flashing-metal/rain-diverter/). I've even seen people use upside down drip edges. Works.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the "borders" to your roof, those must start at the top and line all the side to the gutter. This picture is an example (see the copper plate on the side):
[image]